# Display UIAlertView before launching UIImagePickerController

Tags: objective-c, iphone

My app asks the user via a UIActionSheet where they want to import an image from (Photo Library or Camera) and then launches the appropriate UIImagePickerController.

If the user selects Camera I want to first display a UIAlertView with a camera instructions image relevant to the app. This works, however the UIImagePickerController is launched while the alert is still on the screen and appears behind it. How can I launch the camera only once the user has dismissed the UIAlert?

```
-(void) actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
if (buttonIndex != [actionSheet cancelButtonIndex]) {
    // User hasn't canceled, launch chosen photo source
    NSString *selectedButtonTitle = [actionSheet buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];
    if ([selectedButtonTitle isEqualToString:@"Camera"]) {

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Done" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        UIImageView *cameraHelpView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(82, 46, 120, 160)];
        UIImage *cameraTutorial = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cameraTutorial.png"];
        cameraHelpView.image = cameraTutorial;
        [alert addSubview:cameraHelpView];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];

        UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        picker.delegate = self;
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;    
        [self presentModalViewController: picker animated: YES];
        [picker release];
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement a delegate for the UIAlertView and implement alertView:didDismissWithButtonIndex: to launch the UIImagePickerController.